# mysql queries does not work in zend framework 

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_Email extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

protected $_name = 'memberdetail';

    function getUserid($email)
    {   
        $subquery = $this->select()
        ->from('memberdetail', array('memberid'))
        ->where('email = ?', $email);

        $select = $this->select()
        ->from('usertable', array('userid'))
        ->join('memberdetail', 'usertable.userid = memberdetail.memberid')
        ->where('usertable.userid = ?', $subquery);

        $row = $select->query()->fetch();

        if (!$row) {
        echo "User id not found";
        } else {
        return $userid = $row['userid'];
        }


    }

}
```

Hi, I am trying to return the userid from the above queries. However, the queries does not seemed to be executed as I always get refreshed whenever I call this function.

P.S this set of queries were given to me by another member.

Comment: what are you using? how can you select like $this->select?

Comment: why aren't you using something like this? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Comment: my $this refers to my DB table

Comment: Impossible to say what's happening here, since those methods to query a database are not part of standard PHP.

Comment: are you using any framework ?

Comment: yeah I just editted the code. using Zend Framework

Comment: would be helpful to see your database schema as one might think your query looks a bit ugly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like this is being over thought. According to the info provided ***usertable.userid = memberdetail.memberid*** with this being the case your function is simple.

```
/** this function assumes one and only one email will match a memberid
 *  this function can be improved by validating $email as existing in DB
 *  prior to querying DB, should be done at form level but could be accomplished here
 *  with Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists()
 */
public function getUserIdFromEmail($email) {
$select = $this->select();
$select->where('email = ?',$email);

$row = $this->fetchRow($select);//fetch a single row
if (!is_null($row) {//fetchRow returns null if no row matched
    return $row->memeberid;//return memberid as string/integer = usertable.userid
    } else {
      //handle error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would have been useful to tell people you are using Zend framework.

You need to establish a connection to the database for $this as described in steps 1 and 2 in this link:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html/

Comment: In $this->select(), I am already doing the select in the DB table 'memberdetail', so do I need to create a new adapter for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, if it helps:

```
function getUserid($email){        

        $select = $this->select()
        ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
        ->from(array('m' => 'memberdetail'), array('b.userid'))
        ->join(array('b' => 'usertable'), 'b.userid = m.memberid')
        ->where('m.email = ?', $email);

        $row = $this->getAdapter()->fetchAll($select);

        if (!$row) {
        throw new Exception("User id not found");
        } else {
        return $row->toArray();
        }
}
```

Comment: you might want to add a `->toArray` to the `fetchAll()` otherwise you should get an Exception for unknown array key as fetchAll() returns an Object. You'll also need a `->current()` somewhere else you'll have to iterate over the result set

Comment: modified return to incorporate `->toArray()`